# How to place advertisements for an iphone application built on Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am fairly new as to deploying the application on AppStore. App is being developed on Titanium using Javascript and should be over in a months time. This app would be free for download. I ran through some searches regarding placing of ads using xCode but couldnt find anything for Titanium. Anybody has ideas please let me know.

Comment: Refer this link http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/20861/i-found-a-good-way-to-do-app-ads-with-appcelerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anything in XCode in titanium, you just have to wrap it in a module.

[AdMob is one choice.](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4961?214631482)

[You can find more possibilities here.](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com)